# how to track down an exception in GMS internal

Tags: android, exception, ipc

We're getting a few crash reports which originate from the internal GMS part, and have no idea how to figure out why that happens.

The stack trace is always the same:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzh.zzpf(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzt(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzph(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

As I have no idea when or why this happens, there's no way for me to reproduce and debug it, and so I thought that maybe someone might have more information.
I wasn't able to find anything useful so far.

Anyone?
Thanks.